# Calculating distance between two addresses without Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, distance

Is there some way **other than using the Google Maps API** to calculate the distance between two addresses (not lat/long points)? The "as the crow flies" distance is fine -- I don't need a driving distance.

I could calculate it using [**Vicenty's formula**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) or the [**Haversine formula**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), but I'd still need to convert my address into a lat/long coordinate.

I can't use the Google Maps API because it requires me to display a map, and I need this distance for an internal calculation on my server.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't about how to calculate the distance, you already know how to do that (Vicenty's formula or the Haversine formula).  Your question is how can I geocode two addresses without using the Google Maps API geocoder.

There are open source geocoders available, if it is the US, most of the data is freely available, if it is not the US you may need to pay to get accurate (enough) data.

Try the results of [this search](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/search?group=google-maps-api&q=open+source+geocoder&qt_g=Search+this+group)

This one has come up often in discussions: http://www.geonames.org/